# Firebase anonymous authentication without LOGIN Button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my Android app I use firebase realtime database but my data is exposed to the world since the "read" is set to true. And it seems that there is only one way to secure the data: Authentication. However my app doesn't really need users to login. So showing a LOGIN button is useless and not suitable in my case. Is there a way to Authenticate silently (automatically) in the background without users being aware of it?

Also, is there a way to log in the same user with the same id even when they restart the app?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to identify various users without requiring them to sign in, you can use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). Read the docs for details, but it can be as simple as:

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
     .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```